# Using App Script to Pull Reports from GA4 Data API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am Kinda new to AppScript and wanted to know how I can add multiple dimensions and metrics to the code below as well as how the filtering works. Your help is much appreciated.

Here is my reference and sample code:https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/analyticsdata

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example]

Answer (score 1):

Using the sample code from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/analyticsdata.
Here is an example how to add 'sessions' metric to the request:

```js
function runReport() {
  const propertyId = 'YOUR-GA4-PROPERTY-ID';

  try {
    const metric = AnalyticsData.newMetric();
    metric.name = 'activeUsers';

// adding additional sessions metric

    const metric2 = AnalyticsData.newMetric();
    metric2.name = 'sessions';

    const dimension = AnalyticsData.newDimension();
    dimension.name = 'city';

    const dateRange = AnalyticsData.newDateRange();
    dateRange.startDate = '2020-03-31';
    dateRange.endDate = 'today';

    const request = AnalyticsData.newRunReportRequest();
    request.dimensions = [dimension];
    
// add additional metric in the array

    request.metrics = [metric, metric2];
    request.dateRanges = dateRange;

    const report = AnalyticsData.Properties.runReport(request,
        'properties/' + propertyId);
    if (!report.rows) {
      Logger.log('No rows returned.');
      return;
    }

    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('Google Analytics Report');
    const sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

    const dimensionHeaders = report.dimensionHeaders.map(
        (dimensionHeader) => {
          return dimensionHeader.name;
        });
    const metricHeaders = report.metricHeaders.map(
        (metricHeader) => {
          return metricHeader.name;
        });
    const headers = [...dimensionHeaders, ...metricHeaders];

    sheet.appendRow(headers);

    const rows = report.rows.map((row) => {
      const dimensionValues = row.dimensionValues.map(
          (dimensionValue) => {
            return dimensionValue.value;
          });
      const metricValues = row.metricValues.map(
          (metricValues) => {
            return metricValues.value;
          });
      return [...dimensionValues, ...metricValues];
    });

    sheet.getRange(2, 1, report.rows.length, headers.length)
        .setValues(rows);

    Logger.log('Report spreadsheet created: %s',
        spreadsheet.getUrl());
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log('Failed with error: %s', e.error);
  }
}
```